# distributional divergence of the gravitational / Coulomb force close to the boundary

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, schwartz-distributions

First of all, I am not sure of the terminology here, I am interested in the function $$F(x)=x|x|^{-d},x\in \mathbb{R}^d\setminus \{0\}$$ in dimension $d\geq 2$. I read somewhere that this is called the gravitational force (and I agree in dimension 3, but I am not sure for other dimensions), and elsewhere that this comes from the Coulomb potential.

Anyway, the divergence of this force is $-c_d\delta_0$ in the distributional sense (for some constant $c_d$), i.e. for any sufficiently smooth domain $D\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ not having $0$ in the boudnary and with normal vector $n_D$ on the boundary,
$$
\int_{\partial D}n_D(x)\cdot F(x)S(dx)=-c_d1_{0\in D}.
$$

First question: does anyone knows a good keyword to look upon this function and this kind of facts in the literature? Or a textbook?

Second question: consider now the force of mass spread uniformly over some smooth set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$:
$$
F_A(x)=\int F(y-x)1_A(y)dy.
$$
I'm pretty sure this is well defined, at least outside $\partial A$.
Has the divergence of $F_A$ also a good interpretation in the distributional sense? Ultimately I would like to replace $1_A(y)dy$ by some finite measure $\mu(dy)$...

Comment: $\text{div}\,F_A(x)=1_A(x)$, so well-defined for $x$ not on the boundary of $A$.

Comment: That is surprising because if $A$ is a ball, then $F_A$ is the force of the corresponding "planet", and I think I remember from physics class that $F_A=0$ inside $A$, which would give $div F(x)=0$ for $x$ in the interior of $A$. I was more expecting some measure lying on $\partial A$...

Comment: no, the force of gravity inside a planet is not zero, see, for example, [Journey through the center of the Earth](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Mechanics/earthole.html)

Comment: I see, thanks, I was mistaken between the mass on a sphere and the mass on a ball. When you say $div F_A=1_A$, this is true in any dimension? You think it extrapolates to any measure $\mu$?

Comment: yest, it holds in any dimension, and for any measure $d\mu(y)=\rho(y)dy$, see answer box.

Answer (score 3):

In $d$ dimensions, with a charge/mass density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$, we have
\begin{align}
&F(\mathbf{x})=\frac{1}{2-d}\,\text{grad}\,\frac{1}{|\mathbf{x}|^{d-2}},\;\;\text{div}\,F(\mathbf{x})=-S_{d}\,\delta(\mathbf{x}),\\
&F_\rho(\mathbf{x})=\int F(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}) \rho(\mathbf{y})\,d\mathbf{y},\\
&\Rightarrow\text{div}\,F_\rho(\mathbf{x})=S_d\int\delta(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}) \rho(\mathbf{y})\,d\mathbf{y}=S_d\,\rho(\mathbf{x}).
\end{align}
Here $S_d$ is the surface area of the $d$-dimensional unit sphere.

In the electrostatic context, $F_\rho$ is the electric field from an electrical charge density $\rho$, and the statement that the divergence of the electric field equals the charge density (times a constant) is the first [Maxwell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) (the differential form of [Gauss's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Gauss%27s_law)).

To more specifically answer the question in the OP: the divergence of the force field is discontinuous but finite at the boundary $\partial A$ of a uniform charge density in $A$.

Comment: Ok thanks, but how do you justify switching $\int$ and $div$?

Comment: Well, there is an issue here beause $F$ is not absolutely integrable

Comment: I am probably just missing your point, but you are basically asking for Gauss' law of electrostatics, that the divergence of the electric field equals the charge density; I thought that relation was true even for singular charge densities, at least I have never seen it conditioned on smooth densities.

Comment: Basically I agree with all you said, but I am looking maybe for a textbook doing things in a mathematically rigourous fashion in any dimension. I guess gravitation and electrostatics are more something that happen in dimension 3.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addendum to Carlo's answer, about how to make it rigorous, as per the OP's comments.

Although one can probably do it by hand or brute force, the commutation  of ${\rm div}$ and $\int$ is best shown using Fubini's Theorem for distributions as explained in my answer to [Can distribution theory be developed Riemann-free?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free)

Careful also about what ${\rm div}$ means. Inside the integral it is made of derivatives in the sense of distributions, while outside these are classical derivatives. In the notations used for my answer to the other MO question, $F_{\rho}$ is an element of $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$, the space of temperate smooth functions which embeds into the space of temperate distributions $\mathscr{S}'$. Moreover, one has a commutative diagram, with this embedding turning classical derivatives in $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$ into derivatives in the sense of distributions in $\mathscr{S}'$.

Summary:

In the first line of Carlo's answer, everything in sight (and in particular $F$ and ${\rm div}$) is to be understood in the sense of distributions. However, in the second line $F_{\rho}$ is to be understood as a classical function while $\int$ is in the sense of distributions (I prefer the notation $\langle\ ,\ \rangle_{\mathbf{y}}$).
Finally in the third line ${\rm div}$ is first understood as a classical derivative in $\mathscr{O}_{\rm M}$, then in the sense of distributions in $\mathscr{S}'$, before commutation with the formal integral sign.

Remark: In the above I took $\rho$ in $\mathscr{S}$.