# Extreme confusion with the Gaussian measure on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ supported on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and the issue of Borel sets

Tags: measure-theory, schwartz-distributions

Let
\begin{equation}
C_a(x,y):=\frac{1}{(4\pi)^{n/2}} \int_a^\infty \frac{dk}{k^{n/2}}e^{-km^2-\lvert x-y \rvert ^2/(4k)}
\end{equation}
be a covariance operator with a cutoff $a>0$. Here, $m>0$ is a fixed constant as well.

Then, by the Minlos Theorem, this $C_a$ gives rise to a Gaussian measure $d\mu$ on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ whose covariance is $C_a$ itself.

However, it is known from p.28~29 of "From Perturbative to Constructive Renormalization" (1991) by Vincent Rivasseau that this Gaussian measure $d\mu$ is supported on the space of smooth functions $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

(There are more details on the exact description of the support, but I don't think they are relevant here.)

Now, I am quite confused because $d\mu$ is originally a Borel probability measure on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is equipped with the strong dual topology induced from the nuclear Frechet space $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

On the other hand, $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is most naturally understood as a Frechet space itself, by means of the LF construction with compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Then, how should I understand the following statement:

\begin{equation}
\text{supp } \mu \subset C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)
\end{equation}

Such a confusion with different topologies and corresponding Borel sets is quite frustrating...Could anyone please clarify?

Comment: I believe this is only a set-theoretical statement about the support of $\mu$. Namely, $\text{supp}\,\mu$ is contained in the vector subspace of $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ *whose members can be identified with smooth functions* - to wit, the smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with polynomially bounded growth. That being said, $\mu$ still is a Borel probability measure *on* $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so the topology considered in this subspace must be that induced by $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Oh, I see...Isn't there any way to extend the Gaussian $\mu$ to a Borel measure on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ equipped with the Frechet topology? I dearly hope it to be possible..

Comment: One must be careful here because there are plenty of smooth functions which grow faster than any polynomial (e.g. exponential functions), so the strong (and even the weak) seminorms on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ are *not* continuous on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ w.r.t. the induced topology from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. (to continue)

Comment: (continued) Hence, the first thing to do is to restrict $\mu$ to the Borel subsets of the topology induced on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ by the strong topology of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which can also be induced on the whole of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Even so, because this topology is a lot weaker than the Fréchet topology on $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it's not clear if it's possible to extend $\mu$ from there to all Borel subsets of $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For instance, can the Carathéodory extension theorem be applied in this case? It seems not to me.

Comment: OK, I found some relevant paper..https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81958993.pdf

Comment: According to p.257 Corollary 5.3 applied to $X=C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the Frechet topology, we may find a Borel extension of $\mu$ as long as the original Borel $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is "countably generated".... But is this true??

Comment: Let $\rho$ be the non cutoff massive free measure on $S'$.    Convolution $S\times S'\rightarrow O_M$ is hypocontinuous, so if the mollifier in $S$ is fixed we get a map $A:S'\rightarrow O_M$ which is continuous and thus Borel measurable. For a suitable Gaussian mollifier let $\nu$ be the push forward of $\rho$ by $A$. Now we also have a natural inclusion map $B:O_M\rightarrow S'$ which is also continuous. Take the push-forward $\omega$ of $\nu$ by $B$.

Comment: For suitable choice of the Gaussian mollifier, we should have as Borel measures on $S'$ the equality $\omega=\mu$. This follows from the uniqueness part of Bochner Minlos and the abstract change of variable formula for pushforward measures. By construction $\mu$ can then be seen as living in the subset $B(O_M)$ inside $S'$. I couldn't edit the above comment but my point is $C^{\infty}$ is not a good space to work on given the context, and $O_M$ is a more natural choice.

Comment: If you really want $C^{\infty}$ for some reason (strange to me) then take the pushforward of $\nu$ by the inclusion map $C:O_M\rightarrow C^{\infty}$. All these space carry their natural topology.

Comment: For the hypocontinuity see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72450/can-distribution-theory-be-developed-riemann-free/351028#351028

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic answer. Just one thing: what exactly is $O_M$ in your notation? It does not seem to be defined in the link either.

Comment: Also, definition of hypocontinuity does not seem explicitly presented in the link either. I would be extremely grateful if you mention any relevant reference I can read myself.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam ah yes, the pushforward of $\nu$ from $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)=O_M(\mathbb{R}^n)=$ the aforementioned space of smooth functions with polynomially bounded growth (modulo the usual identification of smooth functions with the corresponding distributions - I'm omitting the map $B$ for notational convenience) to $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ through the natural inclusion map should work *if* such map is Borel measurable. The key point here is that this is only true... (to continue)

Comment: (continued) ...if one uses the natural (Fréchet) topology on $O_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the one induced by $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ doesn't work, so one has to use $\nu$ instead of $\mu$. Good point.

Comment: @Isaac a bilinear map $\beta$ from $E\times F$ to $G$, where $E,F,G$ are (Hausdorff) locally convex vector spaces, is said to be *hypocontinuous* if for any bounded subsets $K\subset E$, $L\subset F$ the restrictions of $\beta$ to $K\times F$ and to $E\times L$ are *jointly* continuous. This is stronger than separate continuity but weaker than full (joint) continuity. A standard reference on hypocontinuity is G. Köthe's "Topological Vector Spaces II" (Springer-Verlag, 1979), Section 40, pp. 153ff - the concept goes back to Bourbaki.

Comment: I see...Wait. When you say that the convolution map $S \times S' \to O_M$ is hypocontinuous, what topology is given on $O_M$ exactly? For $S$, it would be the Frechet topology and $S'$ the strong dual topology. But for $O_M$, is it the subspace topology of $S'$ or something else? It seems like something else according to the above link...

Comment: $O_M$ is not the intersection of $S'$ and $C^{\infty}$

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam wait, you're right... $O_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is actually smaller than $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. It's also required that *all* derivatives are polynomially bounded (the first condition is unable by itself to control derivatives of nonzero order). Sorry y'all! Anyhow, that doesn't change the remainder of the discussion.

Comment: @Isaac I believe Abdemalek's statement about the hypocontinuity of convolution assumes the natural topology on $O_M(\mathbb{R}^n)$, which is given by the seminorms $\|u\|_{\alpha,\varphi}=\sup\{|\varphi(x)\partial^\alpha u(x)|\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}^n\}$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ is a multi-index and $\varphi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Since the latter space is separable, this is still a Fréchet space topology. Notice that this topology is stronger than that induced by $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, since $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)\supset\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Is $O_M$ a Frechet space with the topology induced by $\lVert \cdot \rVert_{\alpha ,\phi}$? There is no explicit statement regarding this issue in any reference.

Comment: @Isaac Hmm... that might be wrong as well. At first glance I thought that separability of $\mathcal{S}$ would take care of it, but digging deeper showed to me that Valdivia proved (Math. Z. 177 (1981) 463-478), using a previous partial result due to Grothendieck, that $O_M$ is topologically isomorphic to the completed projective tensor product $s\hat{\otimes}s'$, where $s$ is the space of rapidly decreasing sequences. Now, $s$ is metrizable but $s'$ is not.

Comment: Better thinking, I don't know why I thought $\mathcal{S}$ being separable would make $O_M$ Fréchet... By a similar reasoning one might guess that the weak topology of $\mathcal{S}'$ is Fréchet, and that is definitely not the case... I must be tired. I apologize for that. I may delete some of my comments above in the near future to prevent confusion.